# Save the current progression with countdown date - progress bar bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I want to create the dynamic countdown date progression using progress bar bootstrap 4
we can set the percentage to display the progress on the label using width style, but the input will be using date format (it will be inserted on admin). So here is what i did:

1. when the date is inserted on admin, I take it, and then on JS i do calculation to take the seconds, which is 
   "(Deadline date that inserted on admin) - (current date time now)" = I will get the dynamic in seconds of the remaining time from here

   ```
       var countTime = #{(properties.countdown_date.to_datetime.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S').to_time - Time.now.to_datetime.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S').to_time).to_i}
   ```

   `properties.countdown_date` = is a method to call the deadline date which is inserted on admin, the format example is: DD-MM-YY H:M:S (31-03-2021 14:15:00)
2. placed the `countTime` into width style

   ```
   <div class="progress" style="height: 1.3rem">
     <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="25" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar">
     </div>
   </div>

   $(".progress-bar").css("width", countTime+"%");
   ```

But i realize that the percentage is still on seconds, so i need to convert it again into percentage divide from 100%, from the remaining seconds of the time.
Any idea how to do that? Thanks

Comment: you need three date_time values for making a percentage value. start time, current time, countdown_date.

Comment: countdown_date is already there which is `var countTime`..
`countTime` is a calculation from start time - current time.. and the result is in seconds

Comment: where is your count down starting time is stored?

Comment: that is inserted from admin, it will be call using method `properties.countdown_date`.. the format is: DD-MM-YY H:M:S.. example= 31-03-2021 14:15:00

Comment: I already got the countdown remaining time, but it's still in seconds.. I need to convert into percentage value divided from 100%.. so when `countTime` reach 0 seconds, it will become 100%

Comment: countTime is the interval in seconds between current time and end time. you need the interval in seconds between start time and end time to calculate percentage. you have to save the datetime as when the timer is set.

Comment: There is no start time to start the progress bar, because when you insert the deadline on admin, the countdown is started.. the user only insert deadline datetime, and will automatically start and minus the current datetime.. when the deadline is equal with current time, it will become 0 seconds and the value is 100%

Comment: There must be some timestamp which is set while inserting deadline datetime. otherwise there is no enough data to calculate the progress. Without knowing start time, how will you calculate how much time has already past. check the code deeper instead of just playing with countdown_date function and unnecessary conversions of its result format.

Comment: alright, can you give the calculating or logic example for that? from the 3 elements you already said include the start time, into become the percentage value

Answer (score 1):

Suppose countdown_date is the deadline value and deadline_created_at_time is the timestamp when deadline is created, in `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`

Then

```
total_time_in_sec = countdown_date.to_i - deadline_created_at_time.to_i
time_past = Time.now.to_i - deadline_created_at_time.to_i
percentage = time_past/total_time_in_sec.to_f*100
```